# Probability Question with Harmonic series

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, harmonic-numbers

I'm struggling hard with this problem since to be honest I have no clue from where to start. I'd love to share with you my efforts on solving but unfortunately I have none. I think I should use Poisson variable to solve it though.
Here's the question:
An album of figurines contains 150 figurines, which are sold in packs of 5 each. Using Approach

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n} = \ln(n+0.5)+0.5772$$

Determine how many packages I need to buy on average to complete the album.

Thanks in advance!

Answer is 167.74

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem). Let $N$ be a random variable representing the number of required buys to collect all $150$ figurines, and $n_i$ be the number of buys to collect the $i$th figurine after $i − 1$ figurines are collected for $i\in[1,150]$. The probability of getting a new figurine is given by $$p_i = \frac{150 − (i − 1)}{150}$$ and $n_i\sim {\tt Geometric}(1/p_i)$ whose mean is also $1/p_i$. 
Obviously,
$$N=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_{150}$$
Using the linearity of expectation we have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}N&=\mathsf{E}n_1+\mathsf{E}n_2+\cdots+\mathsf{E}n_{150}\\
&=\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p_{150}}\\
&=\frac{150}{150}+\frac{150}{149}+\cdots+\frac{150}{1}\\
&=150\left(\frac{1}{150}+\frac{1}{149}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1}\right)\\
&=150(\ln(150+0.5)+0.5772)\\
&=838.6745
\end{align}$$

But since they are sold in packs of $5$, we need to divide it by $5$ which gives $167.7349$.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. I really had no clue what this problem was known and how to solve. Much appreciate!

Comment: My pleasure. It applies to many different problems.